# Songs are not switching in Windows 10 Mobile when phone is locked

Tags: windows-10-mobile, music

I've recently updated my Microsoft Lumia 640 to Windows 10 Mobile. The huge problem I am facing now is, when I open any music player (I've already tried a lot of them), and lock my phone (by pressing power button), songs are not switching to the next one in the playlist. 
To make the next song play, I have to unlock the phone, then it starts immediately. This is super annoying. Has anyone had this issue? Is there some kind of config option to fix this? Is there ANY way to fix this, because it is nearly impossible to listen music on my phone now. I've already tried the following:

1. Phone is not running in battery saver mode.
2. Settings -> Privacy -> Background Apps: Grrove Music and Perfect Music players are allowed to run in the background. I tried them both to listen music with locked phone.
3. Installed [Touch and Lock](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Touch-and-Lock/9NBLGGH0B6C7) application and locked the phone with it instead of power button.

Comment: Is this listening on speaker, through headphones, using a headset (i.e. with mic), or via Bluetooth?

Comment: @RowlandShaw usual headphones, no mic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the recent update the problem has gone away. I believe they fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

**Update:** The problem was fixed in the build *10.0.10586.218*

Make sure that

1. you have not restricted the background activity of Groove Music
   player.
2. your phone is not running in battery saver mode.

Comment: I do not use groove music player. Background activity restriction - is this windows feature or Groove Music player feature. Phone is not in battery saver mode.

Comment: Okay. .Restricting background activity is an OS feature. Go to *Settings->privacy->Background Apps*. Make sure the music player you use is allowed to run in background.

Comment: yes, it is ....

Comment: @DmytroTsiniavskyi Can u spot Groove on the list, some music players may use Groove as backend. Enable background running of Groove. Also try locking your phone via app like [Touch and lock](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Touch-and-Lock/9NBLGGH0B6C7) instead of the power key.

Comment: Yep, I've did everything you said. Still no success..